# Magento2: How to override magento tier price in custom extension?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, tierprice

Need help with Magento2. Anyone know how to override Magento Tier Price. Actually  i am developing an extension and stuck here.

Comment: What you mean 'overwrite'? Please describe more what you need.

Comment: I want to display customized tier price block in place of default tier price block. It means I want to display Tier Price in drop down not in label.

Answer (score 2):

Tier Price is displayed in below  template

> Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml

First, you need copy this template to own extension.

Second, you need add layout update with name `catalog_product_prices`  to overwrite base template.

```
<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[ModuleName]::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                </item>
             </item>
       </argument>
    </arguments> 
</referenceBlock>
```

And last one, modify template as you need.

Comment: Not working :( Stil it calls default file (Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml)

Comment: Do you add   sequence on Magento_Catalog to you module.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The top answer here by KAndy should work as long as you use a `referenceBlock` instead of `blockReference`.